# Pass Javascript Question Mark operator multiple statements?

Tags: javascript

I have a variable that I want to check if it is empty.  I want to know if I can pass multiple statements if the check is true or false, like:

```
var checkme = '';

if(checkme == ''){
     checkme = 'something new';
     do_this();
}else{
     checkme = '';
     something_else();
}
```

but using the `?` operator instead.  Something like:

```
checkme == '' ? (checkme = 'something new') (do_this()) :
                (checkme = '') (something_else());
```

I hope you get what I mean by that.  I actually got something like that to work, but the console of the browser doesn't like it.  Is there a way to properly do this, or do I need to write out the `if...else` statement?

Comment: Use `&&` or `||` in between two conditions

Comment: What's the problem with `if {...} else {...}` ?

Comment: The ternary operator is for assignment, please don't use it to execute code. `if-else` is the right tool for that.

Comment: I couldn't find anything that told me not to, so I was curious.  Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yeap you can do. Example below & *[**fiddle**](http://fiddle.jshell.net/L6w4xmua/)*:

```
var a = true;

a ? (console.log(1 + 1),console.log(2+2)): 
    (console.log(false), console.log(false))
```

your case :

```
checkme == '' ? (checkme = 'something new', do_this()) :
                (checkme = '', something_else());
```

Just separate your commands with coma. 
***[Mozilla Doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)***

Thanks.

Comment: Hey! That works!  I tried using a comma between what I had, but not in the exact syntax you gave.  And since you linked actual documentation I feel a bit better using it.

Answer (score 3):

```
checkme == '' ? ((checkme = 'something new') && (do_this())) :
            ((checkme = '') && (something_else()));
```

as Tushar said

Answer (score 2):

It works even shorter, if the position of the function call is not important.

```
checkme = checkme ? (something_else(), '') : (do_this(), 'something new');
```

Comment: It's definitely helpful for my understanding of how this statement works.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

if you really need to have fun doin it like that:

```
window[checkme == '' ? (checkme = 'something new') &&  'do_this' : (checkme = '') && 'something_else']()
```

this will look for the function by string and execute it and also assign the new value

Comment: in `(checkme = '') && 'something_else'` the second operand is never reached, because `''` is evaluated as falsey.